# How do I set up my Firebase firestore rules for my personal portfolio website?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This may be a very noob question but how do I set up my rules?

I have created a website which reads data from firestore and I need to the data to be read by anyone but can only be edited by me. This is the sample code I tried:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow public read access, but only content owners can write
    match /some_collection/{document} {
      allow read: if true
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_uid;
    }
  }
}
```

as well as:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**} {
        allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

For both of these, my website wasn't able to receive data from the database.

Edit: To show the query that isn't working. I used vueJS for this:

```
mounted() {
      const db = this.$firebase.firestore();
      let storage = this.$firebase.storage();
      let storageRef = storage.ref().child('images');
      db
        .collection('projects')
        .onSnapshot(snap => {
          const info = [];
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            let data = doc.data();
            let imgName = data.img
            storageRef.child(imgName)
            .getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              data.img = url
              // console.log(data.img)
            }).catch((error) => {
              // Handle any errors
              console.log(error)
            });
            data.index = doc.id;
            info.push(data);
          });
          this.info = info;
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query that isn't working the way you expect.  It should be clear how that query would be affected by the rules.  Rules by themselves aren't meaningful without also knowing the specific queries that they are intended to allow.

Comment: @DougStevenson is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query here is on the collection "projects", but your rules only allow queries against a collection called "some_collection".  I would expect the query you show here to always fail given the rules you also show.  Either you used the wrong collection name, or your rules simply do not match what you're trying to do with your query.

Also, you cannot have two completely different sets of rules for one database.  All the rules must be together in the same set.

Comment: Thanks that helped!